# SQL Server 2012 to store DATE in dmy format

Tags: sql-server

By default SQL Server database tables are storing dates in "YYYY-MM-DD" (2020-09-24) format.

Instead, I want dates to be stored in "DD-MM-YYYY" (24/09/2020) format.

Please advise.

Comment: By default SQL Server, if using a date/datetime datatype (as you should), doesn't store the date in a format at all. Format is a function of displaying the data, not storing it. Which is as it should be. If you want to display it in a different format, do it in your front end, or if you must do it in a query use `format` or `convert`.

Comment: Thank you  Dale K, Appreciated your support. I got it... much appreciated.